# SSH direct command execution with nohup

Tags: linux, shell

I can directly exec the command with this.

```
ssh ubuntu@myroot.com ls -la
```

However I want to use command like `nohup sh heavytask.sh &`

Even after quitting connection this task continues works.

So,what I try this

```
ssh ubuntu@myroot.com nohup sh heavytask.sh &
```

However it needs to wait task finished.

Is there any solution for this purpose?

Comment: I am not sure, if the `&` is correct. It guess it would be handled as the `&` for ssh and not for `nohup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O redirection should fix your issue, e.g.:

```
ssh ubuntu@myroot.com "nohup sh heavytask.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null < /dev/null &"
```

Comment: It works well for my purpose. I need to learn more about I/O redurection though....